# Should I nest repositories like Russian dolls?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, repository, composition

**tl;dr** Can I have a repository depend on another repository, where they both implement the same interface?

I am working on a website analytics system that involves getting data from different sources. One of these sources is very slow for large datasets and the other is deprecated and we are moving away from it.

```php
interface TrafficInterface
{
    public function getVisits(DateTime $from, DateTime $to);
}
```

I already have an interface (`TrafficInterface`) for retreiving the data from either source.

```php
class TrafficRepository implements TrafficInterface
{
    private $client;

    public TrafficRepository($apiClient)
    {
        $this->client = $apiClient;
    }

    public function getVisits(DateTime $from, DateTime $to)
    {
        // get data from an API
    }
}
```

`TrafficRepository` is used to access the data from the current tracking system.

```php
class LegacyTrafficRepository implements TrafficInterface
{

    public function getVisits(DateTime $from, DateTime $to)
    {
        // get old data that is stored locally
    }
}
```

`LegacyRepository` is used to access data from the old system that is stored locally as JSON files.

I want to create further repositorys that use `TrafficRepository` and `LegacyRepository` as dependencies.

```php
class CachingTrafficRepository implements TrafficInterface
{

    private $repository;

    public CachingTrafficRepository(TrafficRepository $repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public function getVisits(DateTime $from, DateTime $to)
    {
        // check the cache for data, delegate to the repository if not
        // return data
    }
}
```

`CachingRepository` reduces the problem with the slow API. As the data from the API will not change after the current period (day, week, ...) it can be cached forever.

It wraps `TrafficRepository` and handles adding data to the cache when it is not already there.

```php
class TransitionalTrafficRepository implements TrafficInterface
{
    private $legacy;
    private $caching;

    public TransitionalTrafficRepository(LegacyTrafficRepository $legacy, 
        CachingTrafficRepository $caching)
    {
        $this->legacy = $legacy;
        $this->caching = $caching;
    }

    public function getVisits(DateTime $from, DateTime $to)
    {
        // get data from the relevant repository
        // combine data and return 
    }
}
```

`TransitionalRepository` handles combining data from each of the sources so we seem to have a single source for the data.

- Is there a a name for this system (other than composition)?
- Are there any problems associated with this?
- Are there better alternatives?

Comment: By the way, in the class java.util.time.Instant was added in Java 8.  It is a much better "Time" class than previously existed in Java...it may be worth replacing Joda for the standard Java class  (depends on the amount/flexibility of your legacy code though)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a a name for this system (other than copmosition)?

Kind of. Having an interface, and then an implementation that implements the interface, while also wrapping another instance of the interface (your `CachingTrafficRepository` should really work against *any* `TrafficInterface`, not just `TrafficRepository`) is called the [Decorator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). Caching is a classic example where it can be used.

Your `TransitionalTrafficRepository` is the classic [Composite Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

Outside of the flexibility note above, these seem like fine cases for these patterns and you're unlikely to find better alternatives - except perhaps eliminating the need for them.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:  **Yes**, your repository can "depend on" another repository.

You may want to look at something like a [Data Access Object (DAO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object).

The point here is that you are hiding HOW you get the data you need.  Your code doesn't have to care if the data came from a Legacy Database, a local file, a complex Hadoop back-end, or on-the-fly mocking.

You'll want your deepest/inner-most repo or dependency to define this core DAO interface.  Then your other repos just add or define new objects that implement this core DAO interface.  You can use Decorators and Composition as necessary in these repos (as @Telastyn suggests).